# Is there a way to change a class variable without adding 'foo = '?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class, and would like to change an object of it (similar to the pop method of lists), without adding an `foo = foo.bar()`

In simpler terms, i'd like to do `foo.bar()` instead of `foo = foo.bar()`. Is this possible in python?
Here's some code that i have, which hopefully furthers understanding:

```py
class mystr(str):
    def pop(self, num):
        self = list(self)
        changed = self.pop(num)  # The particular character that was removed
        self = ''.join(self)  # The rest of the string
    
        # Somewhere in here i need to be able to change the actual variable that pop() was called on

        return changed  # Emulates python lists' way of returning the removed element.


my_var = mystr("Hello World!")
print(my_var.pop(4)  # Prints 'o', as you would expect
print(my_var)  # But this still prints 'Hello World!', instead of 'Hell World!'
# It isn't modified, which is what i want it to do
```

Comment: Assignment to self inside a method doesn't actually change what the instance is. Strings are *immutable*, which is why they don't have a pop method to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but not with `str`.

---

What you're looking for is a way to mutate your object. For most classes you write yourself, doing that is straightforward:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff = 0
    def example(self):
        self.stuff += 1
```

Here, calling `example` on a `Foo` instance mutates it, by changing its `stuff` instance attribute.

---

`str`, however, is immutable. It stores its data in C-level data structures and provides no mutator methods, so there's no way to modify its data. Even if you used `ctypes` to bypass the protection, you'd just get a bunch of memory corruption bugs.

You can add your own attributes in a subclass, and those will be mutable, but if you do that to fake a mutable string, you might as well just not inherit from `str`. Inheriting from `str` in that case will only cause bugs, with some code looking at your "fake" data and other code looking at the "real" underlying `str` data.

---

Most likely, the way to go will be one of two options. The first is to just use regular strings without your subclass or the methods you want to add. The second is to write a class that doesn't inherit from `str`.

Comment: Hm, sounds like a fun project to make my own str class and add all the things it has currently. I'm going to attempt to do this, if i succeed or not i'll post a github link :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by ***encapsulating*** a string, rather then ***inheriting*** from it:

```py
class mystr:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self._str = string

    def pop(self, num):
        string_list = list(self._str)
        changed = string_list.pop(num)  # The particular character that was removed
        self._str = ''.join(string_list)  # The rest of the string

        return changed  # Emulates python lists' way of returning the removed element.

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._str
```

Running the same code with this class instead will print:

```
o
Hell World!
```

Comment: That works wonderfully, i'm going to remake the entire string object in python, so i'll add this to the code once i'm done

Comment: That's a misleading `__repr__` - at most, something like that should be `__str__`. If you've got a `mystr` object `x` and you type `x` at an interactive prompt after you've forgotten what you stored there, something like `mystr('Hello World!')` is going to be a lot more helpful than just seeing `Hello World!`, and something like `mystr('[1, 2, 3]')` is going to be a *lot* more helpful than `[1, 2, 3]` if you have a `mystr` instance wrapping a string that looks like a list.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'll take this into mind, and make it display something like `mutablestr("Hello World!")` instead of `Hello World!`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica A very good point indeed! I didn't think on that and just implemented `__repr__` on the thought that `__str__` takes it if it's not implemented and on the grounds that I'm lazy... ^_^